# I have a simple gray heatmap, how can i get the heavy area

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

I have a simple gray heatmap like
[image]

how can i get the heavier area.
im a new one to deal with image.
i tried `_, thresholded = cv2.threshold(gray_image, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)`

no matther what thresh i set, it still cover almost every coloured pixel in the thresholded.

after that i think i may wrongly understand the 'cv2.threshold' so i tried `_, thresholded = cv2.threshold(gray_image, 0, tresh, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)` then i got nothing.

Comment: Can you provide the sample code, which can produce the same result?

Comment: Can you please respond to my answer. In case it doesn't answer your question, I may still help finding the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`cv2.threshold` is not designed to work with white background, we may invert polarity for creating a black background.

We may use `thresh = 254`, and getting the output as black on white.

A more useful solution is inverting polarity (invert black and white) before using `cv2.threshold`.

Assuming `dtype` of `gray_image` is `np.uint8` then white equals `255` and black equals `0`.
Invert polarity: `inv_gray_image = 255 - gray_image`.

---

Code sample:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

gray_image = cv2.imread('gray_image.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # Read image in grayscale format

# Invert black and white before applying the threshold
inv_gray_image = 255 - gray_image

thresh = 1  # 1 is just an example - we may use thresh = 100...

_, thresholded = cv2.threshold(inv_gray_image, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

cv2.imwrite('thresholded.png', thresholded)  # Save image for testing
```

---

`thresholded`:
[image]

---

For finding the area, we may use `cv2.findContours`, and finding the bounding rectangle of the largest contour.

Example:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

gray_image = cv2.imread('gray_image.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # Read image in grayscale format

# Invert black and white before applying the threshold
inv_gray_image = 255 - gray_image  # Valid if gray_image.dtype is uint8
# inv_gray_image = np.iinfo(gray_image.dtype).max - gray_image

thresh = 1

_, thresholded = cv2.threshold(inv_gray_image, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

contours = cv2.findContours(thresholded, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[0]  # Find contours
c = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)  # Find largest contour

x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)  # Get the bounding rectangle
bgr_image = cv2.cvtColor(gray_image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)  # Convert to BGR for drawing colored rectangle
cv2.rectangle(bgr_image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)  # Draw green rectangle.
cv2.imwrite('bgr_image.png', bgr_image)  # Save image for testing
```

---

Output:
[image]

Comment: `cv.threshold()` knows some `*_INV` flags that will handle this without explicit inversion of the input

Comment: You are right: `cv2.threshold(255 - gray_image, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)` is equivalent to `cv2.threshold(gray_image, 254-thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)`.